# Readout Error in Qiskit: What is a reasonable model?

Tags: qiskit, measurement, noise, error-mitigation

The Readout Error in Qiskit is described here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.ReadoutError.html

Although it is easy to obtain such an error for 1-qubit for IBMs available QPUs it's very unclear as to what is a reasonable 2-qubit readout error or n-qubit readout error and how to construct it.

Where can one find information for modelling such errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this
https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/master/ignis/measurement_error_mitigation.ipynb
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/simulators/3_building_noise_models.ipynb

Comment: Nope, not at all actually. I am looking for a reasonable/realistic way to construct multi qubit noise models. By "way" I do not mean code, it's all in qiskit documentation, I mean, given an x-qubit machine, how to construct a realistic x-qubit readout noise model.

Comment: @Marion do you mean like fake device

Comment: No. I mean that IBM provides the 1-qubit error probabilities, that is $p(1|0) > p(0|1)$ but they don't tell us how to construct a realistic multiqubit readout error.